# N columnas en mysql

Tags: mysql

Que tal, tengo una duda tal vez muy básica, pero de verdad no le consigo la vuelta.
Estoy diseñando una tienda online donde quiero poder tener la libertad (como administrador) de crear combinaciones a mis productos y a estas combinaciones poder asociarle una imagen.

Por ejemplo:

Si es un zapato, rojo, talla 8 la imagen a mostrar sera `foto1.jpg`
Pero si es un zapato, rojo, talla 8, cordón negro la imagen a mostrar es `foto2.jpg`

Mi dilema esta en que el usuario puede unir N características y al final estas tendrán solo una imagen asociada...

Actualmente tengo estas tablas:

```
+Característica:
id
valor
id_grupo

+Grupo:
id
Nombre
```

Entonces por ejemplo yo puedo crear el grupo de características "talle" y en la tabla "características" agrego el valor (S, M, L)

Hasta ahora bien... Entonces:
Lo que necesito es algo como:

```
+Tabla_Combinaciones:
id
Url_imagen
característica1
característica2
característica3
. 
.
.
Característica N
```

Es por esto mi dilema pues se que no puedo tener N columnas indefinidas... Pero de verdad no se como modelarlo de manera óptima

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar una tabla con varios casos posibles? Según lo planteas es tan abstracto, que cuesta verlo... En principio, te sugeriría meter la foto como una característica más aunque, como no lo veo del todo claro, mejor espero a que modifiques la pregunta...

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score -1):

A riesgo de equivocarme por no conocer en profundidad tu problema, te propongo el siguiente modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y te lo explico un poco:

- `grupos` registra aquellas categorías en las que quieras agrupar los artículos: temporada (primavera-verano, otoño-invierno), tipo de evento (casual,cocktail,deporte), usuario (señora, caballero, niño, niña), etc. Se vincula con articulos a través de la relación agrupan con cardinalidad n:n por si un artículo pertenece a varios grupos
- `artículos` son los artículos en abstracto: zapatos, bolso, cartera, ...
- en `caracteristicas` defines aquellos elementos que definen a un zapato, un bolso o el artículo que proceda: talla, color, foto, ... La relación `definen` también es n:n porque la característica `color` la pueden compartir varios artículos
- `objetos` con los artículos concretos, los que puedes tocar, los que ya tienen un color y una talla definida cuyo `valor` se almacena en la relación `concretan`.
- `r` únicamente está para que sepas de qué tipo de artículo es cada objeto y así puedas saber qué características tienes que concretar para que quede completamente definido.

Si necesitas más detalles, ponme un comentario y te amplío la respuesta.